# Update / Render Loop faster on successive iterations

Tags: java, loops

I am creating a custom interface-screen in java. Part of this interface-screen takes a given image and then chops it up into a given number of sections randomly and then draws them on the screen with slight movements. Over the top of this is drawn an overlay which blots out most of what is going on underneath. This was obviously very inefficient as much of what was being drawn could not be seen and (I thought) it was causing the interface-screen to stall briefly when first start. I amended the code so that only the sections that can be seen through the overlay are drawn expecting this to fix the problem of slow down at start up but it hasn't.

When I print out the timings for my draw loop the first three times are high: about 500ms, then 300ms, then 20ms and the rest are a stable 16ms (or 60 fps) for the rest of the time.

Is there anything else that might be causing this slow down at the start? Is it possible that java is somehow optimising my drawing in those first 1000 or so ms so that it can run at 16ms for the rest of the time? (Like realising that some of what's being drawn can't be seen and then optimising so it isn't actually drawn every update) - I don't really know I'm sort of out of ideas as to what could be causing this.

I've checked thoroughly to make sure no objects/threads/assets are being loaded once the update starts, this is the only thing I can think of.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Read more about Java JIT: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many loops in Java behave like this. It is because the JVM can store and run code in two forms: slow bytecode or fast native code. Bytecode is the default because creating the native code is expensive. As the program executes, the JVM gathers information about parts of the program it would be worthwhile to convert to native code; this is called *just in time* compilation of the code. So as your program executes it gets faster.

Comment: Is there a way to mark something as "native code" from the start? So that a particular part runs fast from the start.

Comment: Not really. The JVM compiles to native code if a method is called very often. A command line option controls how often is often enough.